# arrays splitting strings java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm sure this is a fairly easy question for someone but I cant work out the best way to do it as a relative beginner.

I am splitting a large file (the string temp) into about a 100 strings and setting it as an array, but I don't know the exact number of strings.

```
String[] idf = temp.split("===========");

String class1 = idf[0];
String class2 = idf[1];
String class3 = idf[1];
etc etc..
```

What is the best way to ensure that I can split all the strings and store them in an array?

Any suggestions or pointers would be most appreciated thanks!

Comment: *to ensure that I can split all the strings* -- you'll always be able to split your file. If your delimiter is not present, you'll just have a big chunk but it's no problem. What is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
String list = "hey there how are you";
String[] strarray = list.split("\\s+");
for (String str: strarray)
{
    System.out.print(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for me this makes the most sense and it works in my code

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to iterate over your `String` array.
You can do it like that:

```
for(String s : idf) {
  //operate on s here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for-each` to get elements from array.
Please look at [oracle official site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for for-each loop.
Consider below code.

```
String tempString = "";
String regex = "";
String[] temparray = tempString.split(regex);
for (String temp : temparray)
{
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```